# Compile Error when using System.out.printIn in Java

Tags: java

I am using System.out.printIn in this program  :

```
public class Program{
      public static void main(String[] args){
      System.out.printIn("JA");
      System.out.printIn("Va");
      }
```

But whenever I try to compile it, I get this error in cmd:

> Program.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
>         System.out.printIn("JA");
>                   ^
>         symbol:   method printIn(String)
>         location: variable out of type PrintStream
>       Program.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
>         System.out.printIn("Va");
>                   ^
>         symbol:   method printIn(String)
>         location: variable out of type PrintStream
>       2 errors

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: printIn ?? it's print ln ? There is no method called ptint`eye`n. It's print`ell`n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's println not printIn.
See the difference of L and I

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Program{
      public static void main(String[] args){
      System.out.println("JA");
      System.out.println("Va");
      }
}
```

try this . Some typo error

Comment: The only answer to use code markup, which __actually__ shows the difference

Answer (score 0):

Its System.out.println(..)

But you typed it as System.out.**printIn().** typo error.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use System.out.println() or System.out.print().

Answer (score 0):

You have made typo error. There is nothing such has printIn, it is println/

```
public class Program{
          public static void main(String[] args){
          System.out.println("JA");
          System.out.println("Va");
          }
```